# Having trouble understanding how to express real world problem to opensolver or minizinc for worker allocation

Tags: excel, solver, knapsack-problem, constraint-programming, minizinc

I am going to start off with that I am not well versed in Minizinc nor constraint programming, I have watched excel "solver" tutorials on youtube which I can understand, but I do not see how I can translate my issue into a excel solver-able solution, nor Minizinc for that matter.

To explain the issue, I have what I believe is a multi-level knapsack problem, but could be wrong.
Here are what I think are the constraints

```
There are 25 "admin" who supervise over 200 "staff".
Each admin has a unique workload allocation.
Each admin also has to moderate staff 
    that is both equal to or greater than their supervisorial allocation 
    and has the ability to rate their moderation preference
Admin cannot supervise and moderate the same staff member.
Every staff member has to have both a supervisor and a moderator.
```

To wrap my head around the problem I have represented it as a table

[table view of data sample set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjqyV.png)

- a# = admin
- s# = staff
- b  = supervisor
- v# = moderation preference (lower = better)

Taking the attached example we can see

**admin1** is the **supervisor** for **staff1**, **13**, and **17**
They have volunteered to **moderate** **staff2**, **20**, **10**, and **23** in that order (preference).

---

Ignoring all of the above which is my breakdown of the problem
you can simplify the issue as follows

1. every row has an equal or greater number of moderators to supervisors,
2. and every column has both a unique supervisor and moderator (where possible priority is taken into account lower = better).

I hope I have tried to explain the problem well enough and my analysis is not too convoluted, any pointers on how I can solve this so it can be scaled to a much larger data set would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following MIP-model in `MiniZinc` with the solver set to `OsiCbc`.

```
int: n = 10;
int: m = 24;
set of int: ADMIN = 1..n;
set of int: STAFF = 1..m;

array[ADMIN,STAFF] of var 0..1: supervise;
array[ADMIN,STAFF] of var 0..1: moderate;

array[ADMIN, STAFF] of int: moderateValue = [|
0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,1,0|
3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,2|
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,2,0,1|
0,0,0,0,2,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,2,1|];

% admin member cannot both supervise and moderate staff member
constraint forall(a in ADMIN, s in STAFF)
    (supervise[a,s] + moderate[a,s] <= 1);

% each staff member is supervised by exactly one admin member
constraint forall(s in STAFF)
    (sum(col(supervise, s)) = 1);

% each staff member is moderated by exactly one admin member
constraint forall(s in STAFF)
    (sum(col(moderate, s)) = 1);

% each admin member cannot supervise more staff members than moderated
constraint forall(a in ADMIN)
    (sum(row(supervise, a)) <= sum(row(moderate, a)));

var int: obj = sum(a in ADMIN, s in STAFF)(moderateValue[a,s]*moderate[a,s]);

solve maximize obj;

output ["obj = \(obj)\n"] ++ ["assignment = \n"] ++ [show2d(array2d(ADMIN, STAFF, [if supervise[a,s] = 1 then 1 elseif moderate[a,s] = 1 then 2 else 0 endif | a in ADMIN, s in STAFF]))];
```

I'm not sure if I understood all of your requirements but hopefully the model can serve as a base. Each `admin` member can here put moderation values of 4, 3, 2 and 1 to `staff` members. The objective is then to maximize the sum of the assigned moderations. In the output `1` means admin member supervises staff member, `2` means admin member moderates staff member otherwise `0` is displayed. The data in the model is based on the provided example.

**Edit**: To make `supervise` pre-defined change the following:

```
%array[ADMIN,STAFF] of var 0..1: supervise;

array[ADMIN, STAFF] of int: supervise = [|
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0|
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0|
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0|
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1|
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|];
```

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time to try and help me figure this out.

I realised my previous comment made no sense so I have included an image [link](https://imgur.com/7XdCgHy) to try and explain.

The issue with this is that the green b value is static, so every column has 1 of these, the solver does not have to move these just take into account their location when trying to decide which of the available yellow v# cells to pick for that perticular column.

I hope this followup makes sense.

Comment: What do `b` and `v#` represent here? Is it supervises and moderates, respectively? What is fix and what is to be decided?

Comment: Hi, 'b' represents the predetermined supervisorial role looking at the sample data A1 is the supervisor for s1, s13, and s17.

v# is the variable moderation choices, a1's being s2, s10, s20, and s23.

I hope that helps clarify it.

Comment: Updated the answer with `supervise` predefined.

Comment: Can I check which version of minizinc you are using? I have the latest IDE but its throwing the error "MiniZinc: type error: undefined identifier `moderateValue'" I will try with the previous release as it could be a bug.

Comment: I can copy and paste the code in the answer to MiniZinc IDE and it runs without error.

Comment: I double checked but I am still getting the problem output error https://imgur.com/zSON3x3

Comment: You have accidentally deleted the `moderateValue`-parameter. Just take the code from the original answer, then replace the `supervise`-part with the code after the edit (don't remove the `moderateValue`).

Comment: Got it working, thank you for being patient enough to walk me through it.